# SAML LogoutRequest sent to SingleSignOnService URL

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml

While testing with Azure AD, I can successfully send SAML LogoutRequests to the SingleSignOnService URL endpoint with HTTP-POST binding.

However, Azure AD explains [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol) that LogoutRequests should be sent to the SingleLogoutService URL endpoint instead, with HTTP-REDIRECT binding.

How is it possible that it works when sending LogoutRequests to SingleSignOnService endpoint ? It works well, but is it recommended ?

Comment: Doesn't Azure AD use the same endpoint URL for the SingleSignOnService and SingleLogoutService? That at least has been my experience. Also, does SAML logout actually work? Does Azure AD send a SAML logout response to your service provider? What I've seen is that it doesn't and it simply displays a message requesting the user close the browser.

Comment: @ComponentSpace Yes, it is the same endpoint URL. And yes, SAML logout work, I receive a logout response at the specified SP application logout URL.